# Fedora 25 Running Slow After Software Update

Tags: fedora, performance

I've been running Fedora 25 on my machine for a couple weeks now. I happened to shut down the machine, and there were some software updates that automatically installed. After booting the next time though, my computer is running noticeably slower. Specifically, there is a significant lag for my mouse cursor, and also typing text seems like typing in molasses.

Is there any reason for this? Is there a way I can check my most recent software updates to see what the problem might be? Has anyone else running Fedora experienced this?

Comment: Did this slowdown happen for a longer period of time or was it just temporary? Might be just some background periodic job (e.g. `updatedb`) .

Comment: It's happening currently. I don't believe there are any residual processes running from the update, but how would I be able to determine if this is the result of a background process?

Comment: Is this a Dell laptop? (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1413306)

Comment: @mattdm, no it's a desktop

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 25 is *long* end-of-life, mandatory upgrade. Current version is 31.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with the following.  Install "htop" if it is not already installed...

```
sudo dnf install htop
```

Then run it with

```
htop
```

This is an improvement over the old "top" - and you can look at CPU usage and see if any process (or process tree) is overusing the CPU and therefore slowing you down.

Comment: I dont' believe it's a process. In the boot menu I booted an older instance of Fedora 25 and it ran just fine. When I shut that instance down and updated the software however, I have the same problem. I have no idea what is causing this to be so sluggish...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of bugs/issues and possible work arounds [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1278587) and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1282232).

Comment: These don't really seem to be related to the problem I described unless I'm missing something.